# Custom Info View Controller index

Tags: tvos, avplayerviewcontroller, tvos11

Is it possible to change Custom Info View Controller's index in AVPlayerViewController?

**[customInfoViewController](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avkit/avplayerviewcontroller/2868498-custominfoviewcontroller)**

> A view controller that provides client-specific content and controls
>   alongside system-provided information and settings panels. SDK
>
> **tvOS 11.0+**

**Declaration Swift**

> var customInfoViewController: UIViewController? { get set }

**Declaration Objective-C**

> @property(nonatomic) UIViewController *customInfoViewController;

Let's take a look inside of **AVPlayerViewController.h**

...

```
/*!
    @property   customInfoViewController
    @abstract   A view controller to be displayed alongside system-provided info and settings panels.
    @discussion Use this property to provide client-specific content and controls in an additional info view. Implement -preferredContentSize to provide the desired view size.
 */

@property (nonatomic, nullable) UIViewController *customInfoViewController API_AVAILABLE(tvos(11.0));
```

...

By default, it's the second item at info panel (after info tab). I want to show at first index.

Answer (score 1):

**tvOS 15.0**

In `AVPlayerViewController` it is possible to set order of `customInfoViewControllers` by ading them into Array in desired order as following: `customInfoViewControllers = [viewController1, viewController2]`. However if you also have `Info` controller presented (by setting item metadata) , the `Info` controller is displayer always as first and `customInfoViewControllers` are only appended next to it by the order you defined in array. The only solution for you might be just completely disabling `Info` controller by not setting item metadata and setting  just `customInfoViewControllers` alone.

Answer (score 0):

For now it's not possible. Maybe in future releases of tvos.